# How to set up good video support on radeon 3850

Tags: video, hardware, ati

So, I've got radeon 3850 agp card. It seems that all videos and graphics are handled by CPU, according to cpu usage. All effects are enabled and working(like compiz), but videos and 3d are extremely slow and low-fps, though I use proprietary ati drivers. What do I need to do to get normal fps? Ready to answer additional questions.

So, I think 10.7 finally installed, but nothing new happend. Hi-res video still 0.3 fps.(video is 1280x720, screen is 1920x1080).

Decided to show my xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection


Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
```

### EndSection

Thanks everyone, I also wanted to ask: everybody tell me, that this parameter:

```
creitve@localhost:~$ glxinfo|grep render
direct rendering: No (LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT set)
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 3850
```

must be "yes", but I didn't manage to enable it. What do I need to get it running? Im sure, it's 100% related to my problem, right?

Comment: do you have the most recent drivers installed?

Comment: It seems I should install not drivers for 3xxx series but special for AGP cards. I'll check it and tell you if it worked. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

90% of the time this type of problem is resolved by doing a purge and reinstall of the driver stack, because either the mesa GLX driver or the kernel driver is messed up.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver

As far as open source drivers, xserver-xorg-video-ati in Lucid supports 2D but not 3D acceleration for this hardware, so depending on your definition of 'good' it likely isn't going to suffice for you.

3D support is coming in Maverick, although there's still a lot that's incomplete.  See http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature for a detailed breakdown of the 3D support with this driver.  (Your card fits under the R600 column.)

Note that with the open driver and AGP hardware, sometimes you have to tweak AGPMode either in BIOS or (for -ati) in the xorg.conf.  (See 'man xorg.conf' or 'man radeon').

Comment: Well, the both links are about how to remove fglrx and instal opensource drivers. But how to "purge and reinstall the driver stack"? Thats what I did:
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-ati
*reboot*
sudo sh ./ati-driver-installer-10-7-x86.x86_64.run --buildandinstallpkg
finally i got it working, but perfomance is still poor. Or all I need is to surrender and use opensource, while waiting for normal drivers for my card?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the open source drivers? I have a slightly newer card (I think) and the proprietary drivers were slow, buggy, and leaked memory. The open drivers work perfectly. Have a look for the xserver-xorg-video-radeonhd packages.

Comment: The xserver-xorg-video-ati driver is the one to use; -radeonhd is deprecated.

Comment: I can't see anything about it being deprecated at x.org or in it's details in the repos. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place? Regardless, for my card that driver does solve my problems for now. Also, I thought the -ati driver was just a wrapper for the -radeon, -mach64, etc drivers.

Comment: Meant that it's deprecated in Ubuntu, we no longer accept bug reports about it and no longer pull updates to it.  I think upstream is more or less dead, but haven't kept track.  Yes, you can consider -ati to be synonymous with -radeon for most purposes.